# What modern alternatives to Numerical Recipes exist?

Tags: books, algorithms, resources

In the past, the [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) book was considered the gold standard reference for numerical algorithms.  The earliest Fortran Edition was followed by editions in C and C++ and others, bringing it then more up-to-date.  Through these, it provided reference code for the state-of-the-art algorithms of the day.

Older editions [are available online for free](http://www.nr.com/oldverswitcher.html) nowadays.

Unfortunately, I think it is now mostly useful only as a historic tome.  The "software engineering" practices seem to me to be outdated, and the actual content hasn't kept pace with the literature.

What similarly comprehensive yet approachable references should the modern programmer look at instead?

Comment: The algorithms themselves are very good for general purpose problem-solving. It is their implementations that might leave something to be desired. But that is OK because the code in the book is simple enough to modify to whatever your tastes are. The implementations in the chapters are fairly "self-contained" and free of cruft. Numerical recipes is still a good reference for times when you need to implement some basic numerical stuff but don't want/need a huge complex or expensive library or framework.

Comment: As it stands, this question could be considered offensive, it's certainly not very constructive. I have made use of Numerical Recipes throughout my career and would highly recommend it to anyone needing a ready reference for algorithms to solve complex problems. I have never used the code directly, but I have always implemented the algorithms in my own languages using my own preferred interfaces. The problems you appear to see are superficial, and there will usually be better algorithms out there if you care to look, but even then NR is useful to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @MarkBooth I don't intend it to be offensive.  I've used it extensively over the past *too many* years.  I also don't deny that it is still a valuable starting point.  But surely after 20-somethng years, there must be a better alternative?  At least, something that already details those "better algorithms if you care to look" in the same well-written, approachable, format?

Comment: @Angelo I agree that the implementations are fairly self-contained, and they make wonderful "reference implementations" (ignoring the few, well-documented, caveats that apply to some) as I said.

Comment: To avoid controversy, I'd like to state that the current phrase *"The "software engineering" practises seem to me to be outdated"* is neither what I wrote nor what I meant. I was trying to imply that the coding style, and the non-OO, non-functional, form of these examples leads to some criticism/debate. I hope no modern programmer would write similar code, but within the historical context of NR, the style is understood and acceptable to me.

Comment: I have to agree that the C and C++ code provided in the books proves once again that a good Fortran programmer can write good Fortran code in any language. However, these books are still a great reference. The explanations of the algorithms are very clear. The code is usable out of the box, and if it really offends your sensibilities you can always rewrite it yourself. It would still be much easier than to implement it from scratch.

Comment: Remember that the copyright restrictions on the code in NR are quite draconian. You are only allowed to personally key in the code for up to ten routines, and your are NOT allowed to distribute the resulting program to any other person or computer. In almost any working environment this means you are going to have to re-implement the algorithm anyway, so what would be the benefit of the authors providing a sophisticated OO or functional  implementation? The service provided by the book is a clear explanation of important algorithms, not the provision of a strong math library.

Comment: @Charles *"The service provided by the book is a clear explanation of important algorithms, not the provision of a strong math library."*.  I fully agree, but that's the point: what reference provides equally clear and comprehensive explanations of the now-state-of-the-art algorithms, with emphasis on issues that would concern the modern programmer? e.g., parallelism, to name the most glaring concept.

Comment: @Stewart, so you actually are looking for better, more recent algorithms? That doesn't seem to match the question as written and your latter comments which mention software engineering issues, OO, and functional implementations. Maybe you need to further revise the question? I was certainly confused.

Comment: @Charles, in a nutshell, I want it brought up-tp-date: More recent algorithms, new topics of contemporary interest, and a style that better reflects modern software development. Given that this will probably never happen, what should the modern developer use as their "gold standard reference" for numerical methods?

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I was a mathematics student, this book was regarded as something of a joke. I note that their C++ code was particularly bad, also add to that problems with the copyright. Sorry I can't recommend an alternative.

Comment: @Stewart If the current edits to your question don't match what you meant to say, please feel free to edit it again.  One problem of this format is that it is sometimes a bit of a guessing game.

Comment: @Stephen The question is still a valid question that I'm interested in - it is just that the justification I gave for the question has morphed a bit.

Comment: Who cares what the code is like? Wrap it up nicely and never look at it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Also, you are unlikely to have a license to use the code in commercial projects, so you'll need to reimplement the described algorithms anyway. Smelly code will encourage you to actually do that!

Comment: @Stewart I have a license to use the code in my commercial project. You just need to write to them and request permission to use a small number of recipes.

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162136/any-decent-alternatives-to-numerical-recipes) on SO

Answer (score 9):

In terms of Numerical Recipes, we need two things - the understanding of how algorithms translates into programming implementation and second, a reference implementation that books things.

There seems to be *NO* combination of BOOK + Reference software. However, there are some good reference softwares and some of this provides reference to papers on the basis of such an algorithms.

Here is a list of some reference (mostly open source) libraries that might help:

1. [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/manual/html_node/)
2. [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) it has a good *book* as a [user manual](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/index.html)
   There is also [LAPACK++](http://math.nist.gov/lapack++/) and [other (TNT)](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/) derived/related packages. See [this](http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/linear) for more information.
3. [Boost Linear Algebra](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)
4. [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)
5. [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/)

Other specific things are

1. [Apophenia](http://apophenia.info/) for statistical models
2. [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/index.html)
3. [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/)
4. [The R package](http://www.r-project.org/) - and a [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593273842.do)
5. [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)
6. [Intel Math kernel Library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/)
7. For [pattern recognition](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse802/PR_software.html)

You can also check out "[Data Analysis with Open Source Tools](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802363.do)".

Here is a huge list of comparison though i haven't verified everything.
http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html

Answer (score 4):

Numerical Recipes is still, IMO, a useful book. It describes the algorithms really well, including their derivation, the situations in which they're useful, and alternatives to consider when they aren't. I've been using the book for years.

One thing I have *never* used is their code. I always write my own implementation based on the algorithms they describe. In that respect the quality of their code doesn't matter (and it is indeed questionable: in the 2nd edition C book, they define a collection of functions and macros to make arrays unit-indexed because the authors come from a Fortran background). As an example: I once had to implement FFT in Objective-C, so I used NR in Fortran to understand what FFT did and how the code should look.

Think of NR the same way you think of Knuth: you would never paste code from that book into your project.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I like it, it's about the level I can understand

The code is Fortran translated to 'C' but that's OK you can just translate it back to Fortran and then into C++ yourself!  There are advantages to the Fortran or C versions in that the code is pretty much self contained, you don't have to drag in a bunch of C++ classes to do matrices, complex, etc - especially given the quality of their coding!

There is a justifiable objection to the ludicrous copyright claims by the authors and I know a number of lecturers that ban NR in their classes. Among numerical experts the books also have a reputation as "enough information to get you into trouble". But their only suggestion is generally to use their personal code or buy NAG.

A suggested collection of alternate high quality numerical libs is at http://www.netlib.org/